# Django: missing request when try to reach a media file

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework as backend and React as front end, I've created a data base where I upload some articles. These articles contains a title, a body and an image. I'm fetching this data base by axios in React and I'm able to render the title and body, but not the image. I think I have to use the absolute path where the image is store but here is the problem, I can't reach that image.

**Models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    index     =   models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    title     =   models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=150,editable=True)
    img       =   models.ImageField(upload_to='articles/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Django Rest Framework dispatcher

```
{
    "index": 2,
    "title": "First article",
    "img": "/media/articles/14-101.jpg",
},
```

**settings.py**

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**
...

```
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The server does not receive the request when I try to reach 127.0.1.1:8000/media/articles/14-101.jpg.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'problem' (it's not actually a problem, it was my fault) is in the settings.py file, there you can only access to the server via HTTPS so, in order to get access to the image the correct url is:

https://127.0.1.1:8000/media/articles/image_name.jpg

Note the https:// before the IP address. I'm also running the server by the r*unsslserver 127.0.1.1:8000* command.